# MySQL Script Applied to Many Databases

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have one MySQL script and many databases that the script is to be applied.Simplified script is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE aaa1 AS SELECT * FROM dbname1.aaa ;  
CREATE TABLE aaa2 AS SELECT * FROM dbname2.aaa ;  
CREATE TABLE aaa3 AS SELECT * FROM dbname3.aaa ;  
... 

CREATE TABLE bbb1 AS SELECT * FROM dbname1.bbb ;  
CREATE TABLE bbb2 AS SELECT * FROM dbname2.bbb ;  
CREATE TABLE bbb3 AS SELECT * FROM dbname3.bbb ;
```

**My Problem:**

The easiest way that I can think of is applying "USE dbname" inside the stored procedure, but it doesn't work. I searched the internet and some people say dynamic SQL for this. I tried this and that but all of them are not working.

Could you help me resolve this with a working script example? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may write a loop which does `CREATE TABLE` statements.  But, you should give us the actual table and database names.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a sample script that replaces the script above? All db names (dbname1, dbname2, dbname3) are given. Actually the script contains not only a single "CREATE TABLE..." but also many "CREATE TABLE..." and "ALTER TABLE...". That's why I thought "USE dbname" in stored procedures.